# Laravel - Save returns true but not updating the database

Tags: php, laravel-5

```
try{
    $abcd = $cat->save();
    var_dump($abcd);exit; // returns true
} catch (Exception $e){
    echo '<pre>';print_r($e);exit;
}
```

Dumping the data just before save function is printing all correct.

Tried this code - it dumps as true but not getting updated in database.
I have tried all known scenarios. Any exceptional cases that this can happen.?

primary key, id , .... and some other checks are already done.
But no progress.

Comment: Please share some more code

Comment: @AnkurTiwari Can it be any issue with data format? If so laravel will not throw any error?

Comment: @mujuonly pleas show $cat object code how do you create this object please share detail code

Comment: Are you doing this on a relationship? If you want to save parent model as well as all relationships then you should call `push()` instead.

Comment: Upon digging more - It was my fault that the id of updating row was incorrect. Thank you guys for your quick response

Comment: @mujuonly Can you please share some more code related to `$cat` creation and update query?

Answer (score 2):

you need to use `Cat Model` while saving :

like `$cat=new Cat();` for creating new record or,

`$cat=Cat::find($id);` while updating exiting record

```
try{
    $cat=new Cat();
    $cat->some_column='some_value';   
    $abcd = $cat->save();
    var_dump($abcd);exit; // returns true
} catch (Exception $e){
    echo '<pre>';print_r($e);exit;
}
```

Comment: Got here from Google because I couldn't find a good simple example like this. Thank you sir